# Can I develop code on my bq Ubuntu tablet and compile and run it on the tablet?

Tags: application-development, development, tablet, monodevelop, m10

Is there any reason I cannot use my bq Ubuntu tablet in desktop mode to write, compile and run code for Ubuntu development?

Answer (score 1):

There is right know a problem with Ubuntu SDK IDE. It does not work under Ubuntu touch. At least I did not make it work until now.
If that would work you can start developing Ubuntu apps on it.

Comment: Yes is there a way to download what I would need? Thank you very much!